# SDL_image.h fatal error: No such file or directory

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-image

I am using Debian and i downloaded SDL_image.h succesfully. (sudo apt-get install libsdl2-image-dev)

I wrote a simple code to tell if it sees PNG images, but I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>


int main(){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) printf("ERROR SDL_Init() - VIDEO");
    if (IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG) < 0) prinft("ERROR IMG_Init() - PNG");
    
    char fileName[50] = "im.PNG";
    SDL_Texture *image = IMG_Load(fileName);
    if (image == NULL) printf("ERROR image == NULL");

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it on the command line as follows

```
gcc SDL_learnT.c -w -lSDL2 -o SDL_learnT
```

And i am getting Error = "fatal error: SDL_image.h No such file or directory"

**I tried to do the following but the result did not change**
#include <SDL2_image.h> or #include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

Comment: Please don't edit your solution into the question. Post it separately as an answer below, then press the checkmark next to the answer to mark your problem as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
It should be <SDL2/SDL_image.h> not <SDL_image.h>

Compiling with gcc should be as follows (Command Line)

$gcc FILENAME.c -o OUTNAME -w -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** It seems from your latest edit that you've [already] solved your problem, so the following may be moot.

---

Install the development package for `SDL2_image` [which it appears you've already done--sigh].

On fedora, this is:

```
sudo dnf install SDL2_image-devel
```

On ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-image-dev
```

Use `pkg-config` in the `gcc` lines (e.g.):

```
gcc -o program program.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs` SDL2_image
```

or `sdl2-config`:

```
gcc -o program program.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2_image
```

In any case, the correct include is:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

You should be able to do:

```
find -xdev /usr -name SDL_image.h
find -xdev /usr/local -name SDL_image.h
```

Or, some `ls` commands.

Then, compare against the `pkg-config` output.

A last resort ... I've had trouble in the past with SDL2 and ubuntu (bionic). Ultimately, I uninstalled the standard packages and rebuilt/reinstalled from the source packages.

OT:

`IMG_Load` returns a surface, not a texture:

```
SDL_Texture *image = IMG_Load(fileName);
```

should be

```
SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load(fileName);
```

And here:

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) printf("ERROR SDL_Init() - VIDEO");
```

It is not enough to inform about the error, you should exit (or at least skip all SDL functions), a better approach:

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
{
    SDL_Log("SDL_Init: %s", SDL_GetError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, i got the same error again.

Comment: I believe the manual recommends omitting `SDL2/` from the includes. `pkg-config` should've added that directory to the search path.

Comment: @CraigEstey you forgot to link with `SDL_Image` in the `gcc ...` line, edited